# SQL Server 2019 is returning records which are mismatching DateTime condition in the query

Tags: sql-server

I just hit an absolutely unexpected problem.

Ive got a very primitive table which put together Unix timestamp and DateTime. The table script as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hist]
(
    [time] [bigint] NULL,
    [pair] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DateTime] AS (DATEADD(SECOND, ROUND([time] / (1000000000), (0)), CONVERT([datetime], '1970-01-01',(120)))) PERSISTED
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So the output is like this:

```
time                DateTime
-------------------------------------------
1609946564379305356 2021-01-06 15:22:44.000
1609946558002360563 2021-01-06 15:22:38.000
1609946555348782291 2021-01-06 15:22:35.000
1609946554681771971 2021-01-06 15:22:34.000
1609946552162363862 2021-01-06 15:22:32.000
1609946551615328953 2021-01-06 15:22:31.000
1609946551546017601 2021-01-06 15:22:31.000
1609946551508916896 2021-01-06 15:22:31.000
```

But when I'm querying this table with certain time conditions it returns the mismatching records:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [time],
    [DateTime]
FROM 
    [EE_2].[dbo].[Hist]
WHERE
    [DateTime] < CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-06 15:22:34.000')
ORDER BY
    [DateTime] DESC

time                DateTime
--------------------------------------------
1609946703969897863 2021-01-06 15:25:03.000
1609946702008782869 2021-01-06 15:25:02.000
1609946702625778619 2021-01-06 15:25:02.000
1609946702622227680 2021-01-06 15:25:02.000
1609946700549524407 2021-01-06 15:25:00.000
```

However changing operator from '<' to '>' returns no records at all, even though there are corresponded matches, i.e. server thinks that all records are earlier than specified in condition no matter what condition it is

The issue is machine specific as the same table and same DB is working fine on other machines.

Does anyone have any suggestion where to look at? Some localization settings or something else? I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Try using an unambitious string format for your date, such as `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnn`

Comment: Even so, if I use an unambiguous format, or not, I get results back for your sample data, regardless of the language/format: [db<>fidd;e](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a26f70f362bfa5673c20a27217b4852). Take the time to post a [mre].

Comment: I think your computed comlumn calculus is wrong if you try to have a UNIX timestamp. Because UNIX timestamp is wrong (not a real datetime...)

Comment: Unit timestamp is correct. records time is corresponding the actual time

Answer (score 0):

DateTime format are of two differents forms.

1. for datatype DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME you need tu use the short standard ISO SQL format YYYYMMDD hh.mmm.ss.nnn
2. for datatype DATETIME2, DATE, TIME, DATETIMEOFSSET you need tu use the large standard ISO SQL format YYYY-MM-DD hh.mmm.ss.nnn

I bet 1 Millions $ that you have a DATETIME so you need to use

```
**[DateTime] < '20210106 15:22:34.000'**
```

Why ?

DATETIME and SMALDATETIME has been created while the SQL ISO version was SQL 2 (1986) that conventionnaly use the YYYYMMDD date part format.

DATETIME2, DATE, TIME, DATETIMEOFSSET was created in 2008, while SQL 3 (aka SQL:1999) was released by the ISO commitee that changes the format for a better adequation with other relative langages like XML.

By the way DATETIME and SMALDATETIME are deprecated datatype and should not be used in database created after 2008...

---

As a test for the ISO SQL format short or long :

```
SET LANGUAGE English;

DECLARE @D DATETIME = '20211231', @D2 DATETIME2 = '2021-12-31';
SELECT @D, @D2;
GO

SET Language Français;

DECLARE @D DATETIME = '20211231', @D2 DATETIME2 = '2021-12-31';
SELECT @D, @D2;
GO

SET Language Russian;

DECLARE @D DATETIME = '20211231', @D2 DATETIME2 = '2021-12-31';
SELECT @D, @D2;
GO
```

Comment: Why use 2 different formats for the data types? `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` are unambiguous for both; then it doesn't matter what language or data type you're using, you will always get the correct date and time value.

Comment: Thank you for the responce. changing time format makes no difference. I tried all different variations - with zerous or without. it return the same raws

Comment: *"By the way DATETIME and SMALDATETIME are deprecated datatype and should not be used in database created after 2008..."* Neither `datetime` nor `smalldatetime` are deprecated. Yes, it is recommended to use the newer data types in new work, see [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql), but recommended and deprecated are 2 completely different things. In the same regard `THROW` is recommended over [`RAISERROR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql), but the latter is also not deprecated.

Comment: @AntonK this is why I asked for a [mre], as I cannot repro your problem. There is something you aren't telling us here, as the above SQL does return data for the sample you have given us, regardless of the `LANGUAGE` or if you use an unambiguous format.

Comment: Lamu, I don't think you can reproduce this issue as everything is working fine on another machine. The problematic machine is localized version and using Russian langudge.

Comment: Sorry Larnu I a not a native english writer/spoker... For me, in my french mother language a thing that is not recommended use to be deprecated ! And in addition DATETIME has worst performances....

Comment: Language based problems can easily be repro'd. If you take a moment to look at the fiddle you can see I demonstrate how differently an ambiguous string format works for different languages. HOwever, even setting the `LANGUAGE` to `RUSSIAN` [doesn't repro the problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d80f166e9d5a4d6bbd6ccff55930532e). It's *you* who needs to give us a [mre] here.

Comment: No Anton K... Those two ISO SQL datetime formats overpast the session parameters...

Comment: @SQLpro Not recommended means that it's something you should avoid the use of. Deprecated means that it's something that will be removed; and thus you should also avoid the use of. Multi-line table value functions aren't recommend for example (as they are terribly slow), but they have never been, or likely will be, deprecated. The words have completely different meanings. Telling people that `datetime` is deprecated is completely untrue, I'm afraid. I doubt that the data type will ever be deprecated, if I am honest.

Comment: @larnu The main part of deprecated feature will never be remove since SQL Server 2008 Transact SQL language...

Comment: I don't understand that comment, @SQLpro .